# how to pass object data through useNavigation hook in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Below mentioned code is the reactJS page in which i want a button to route me to a detailsPage with some object data mentioned in the horror object

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import DetailsPage from "./detailsPage";

function Horror() {
    let navigate= useNavigate(); //object{navigate:}
    const [horror, sethorrorData]=useState([
        {
            name:"Horror Book 1",
            id:"1",
        },
        {
            name:"Horror Book 2",
            id:"2",
        },
    ]);
```

this is the handleclick fucntion which will send the data to the details page but it is giving an error of location.state = null in the details page which means no data is passing through this function.

```
   function handleClick()
    {
        navigate("/detailsPage",{ state : horror });
        // alert(horrorData[0]);
    }
```

The below code will display a button on the horror page which will onclick display the detailspage but it is not displaying any data there.

```
  return(
        <div>
            <h1 style={{color:"black"}}>Horror Books</h1>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>More details</button>
            {/* <DetailsPage data={horrorData}/> */}
        </div>
    );
}
export default Horror;
```

This is the code of the details page which is use to get the data from horror page through useLocation hook.

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function DetailsPage() {
    let location= useLocation(); 
    alert(location.state) ;
    // console.log(location.state[0]);
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Details</h1>
            alert(location.state) ;

            {location.state.map((val,index)=>{
                return(
                    <>
                    <h4>BOOK NAME: {val.name}</h4>
                    <p>{val.id}</p>
                    </>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
export default DetailsPage;
```

Comment: could you add where and how are your routes defined? We're missing that info

Comment: ` <Routes>
   <route path="/" element={<Fiction/>}/>
     <Route path="fiction">
       <Fiction/>
     </Route>
     <Route path="fiction/:category">
       <Category/>
     </Route>
     <Route path="horror">
       <Horror/>
     </Route>
   </Routes>`

Comment: i had define myroutes as above code ,but the detailsPage is nested inside the horror page. In simple words, there is a button in the horror page which will direct to you on a new Page called detailsPage with all the information about the horror books details.But the main problem is that the data is not going in the detailsPage through state

Comment: Can you undesrtand it now , Ganzalo ?

Comment: If the `DetailsPage` is just a component rendered in `Horror` which ***IS*** rendered on a `Route` then I don't think there's a need to navigate to path "/detailsPage", which *isn't* a path defined in your router. I think you need to un-nest the `DetailsPage` and declare the route/path for it, or nest it in "horror/detail" or similar, or just pass `horror` as a prop to it since it is all on the same page already. Do you have a *running* codesandbox?

Comment: Thank you so much @DrewReese! I just forgot to define detailsPage in my routes. Your comment gives me clear idea about it .Thanks once again